# Python, add an external library in an external file which save functions

Tags: python, external, libraries

I have a Python program which call an external file that contains functions to run the main program. 
(The external file is in the same directory that the main file.)

These functions need to call to the libraries `json` and `os`; however, if I put `import json` or `import os` at the begining this file doesn't load those libraries.

I have to put the functions which need external libraries in the main file.

Here is an example for my code:

```
def acceder_archivos(param1,param2,param3):
    while param3 == True:
        if os.path.exists(param1) and os.path.exists(param2):
            try: 
                obtener_sentimientos(param1,param2)
                param3 = False #salimos del while.
                print('existe:',param3)
            except:
                #manejar el error.
                print('Error al abrir el archivo.')
        else:
            print('Por favor, introduzca el nombre de un fichero que ...")
            param3 = False
            file_sents,file_salida,existe = cargar_archivos()
            acceder_archivos(file_sents,file_salida,existe)
```

In this code the function needs to call the `os` library, and it works if the function is in the main file. But if this function is in an external file, it doesn't run.

Is there any solution for that? I don't find any answer.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Files you import should be perfectly capable of importing files themselves. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Thank you by your answer but doesn't run; I tried before writing the question. That code is complete. You can call it from another file, and you would obtain "NameError: name 'os' is not defined" from the main file.

Comment: I have realized if I use Spyder instead of Jupyter, the files I import are capable of importing files and then the program runs. I don't understand why doesn't run in Jupyter.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('.')
```

I'm not entirely sure why this works but I had a similar problem and this fixed it for me.

Comment: Sorry, but doesn't run. I wrote those lines in the file which contains the functions but there is no changes: give the error "NameError: name 'os' is not defined".